# Assigning modules from a library to a server where the number of modules can change?

Tags: design-patterns

I need to create a design for an internal tool that we will try to utilize within our own team that works with software testing. We will try to build a tool that can help us automatically setup a test system.

I have a list of servers that I want to add multiple modules to. I want to set a number on each module so it will be instantiated that many times in the server. I want to pick the modules from a library of modules displayed to the user.

Is it possible to combine drag and drop from the library to the server and at the same time apply the number of that specific module I want? Please see attached wireframe.

[image]

Comment: Hello Michael, perhaps you can add the research you've done so far or assumption that you have right now, its not in your best interest to receive an answer, without really understanding it. I often find myself, when making assumptions, thinking about how I guess the ideal world would look like, I then draw this on paper and test this out in the hallways.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've tried to make my question more clear and how far I got!

Comment: Okay, thank your for adding this additional information. Now I'll be the critical observer and ask "why must you be able to select a server and its virtual server underneath" - what is the real problem you're trying to solve? A general remark, though, is that I wouldn't probably go suffix the XML extension, unless it has a real purpose to expose this information.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering about the explanation, as the end-result is "i want to emulate a certain amount of certain entities", everything else (server list, ip-addresses, ...) seems clutter... my suggestion would be a list of entities and an amount, the backend should than take care that they are created in this pool of servers.

Think about "what keeps me from doing my job/the task at hand" :-)